"Last year, they didn't take to the stage until 11.30"
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part II Cambridge Choir, chapter 25)

Martin Mussey and him = William are Cambridge choristers


The highlight of the first bleak day back in Cambridge after Christmas has always been sitting at supper listening to Martin tell him about the Mussey Boxing Day Play. Who fell out with who, which soft furnishings were purloined for costume and sets,. . . which boys played girls and which girls played boys - gender reversal was evidently mandatory. It sounded such indulgent fun, putting aside a whole day to write, cast, rehearse, make the set and costumes, and then of course perform it. The older the Mussey children get, the more elaborate they have become and the later the performance time. Last year, they didn't take to the stage until 11.30 because Richard (Martin's brother) insisted mid-afternoon that he rewrote the script in rhyming verse.

I take "they didn't take to the stage until 11.30" to mean 'they didn't perform the play until 11.30', but there is the phrase 'take the centre stage'. It could be the cited words have a related or similar meaning. (As an aside, I know the meaning of 'take the centre stage').

take to something here means to begin or do something. take to the stage=go on stage. [They didn't perform the play, not: they performed the play not until (time)] Also, take center stage is different: take the most important position.

"Take to the water" – go for a swim, or enter the water.

@Lambie, not in this context, but "take to" is often used for doing something adroitly, with verve, e.g., "He takes to skiing like a duck takes to water."

@DrMoishePippik your usage is valid, but so is Lambie's. The characters had been performing their Boxing Day plays for many years, so they didn't 'take to it' in the sense of your example. Perhaps the author should have written "they didn't take the stage..."

The author could have written "they didn't go / get up / show up on stage until... All of those are more "natural, colloquial" than take [to] the stage, which imho is already quite "literary" even with to. But if I heard some saying it without to, I'd probably assume they were being deliberately facetious with such a hifalutin turn of phrase.

See this NGram showing that neither Brits nor Americans usually include the article when talking about taking [the] centre/center stage.

@DrMoishePippik Wrong. MW has this definition: (2)
: to move onto or into : move into position on
the home team took the field
take the witness stand To take to something also means to begin liking to do it. Not doing it adroitly.

"insisted mid-afternoon that he rewrote"  is interesting.

The phrase take to there means "move to, especially en masse".

Everyone, take to the lifeboats! The ship is sinking!


When the revenuers showed up, the moonshiners took to the hills.

The simple verb take in "take center stage", lacking the preposition, does not express movement but is akin to "take the hill" in military contexts, that is, "occupy the position".
